# How to optimize a SQL query that combines INNER JOINs and DISTINCT?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT af.ID, af.nom_flux, st.chemin_stockage, af.hash_flux 
FROM signature sig  
INNER JOIN stockage st ON st.id_flux = sig.id_flux AND st.date_statut_stockage >= sysdate - 100
INNER JOIN allotissement_flux af ON af.ID = sig.id_flux  
WHERE sig.date_statut_signature >= sysdate - 100
AND sig.statut_signature = 'A_SIGNER'
AND st.statut_stockage = 'OUI'
AND sig.nb_appel_service_signature < 4 ;
```

The query above returns me 5222 rows, and it runs locally in 0.63 seconds. I'm wondering if it is as fast as it can be or if I can tweak it further somehow, as this dataset will grow fast overtime.

Things that I've tried without change in speed:

1 - Change the join order, joining from the smallest to the biggest table.

2 - Adding an index to af.ID.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  0.63 seconds seems pretty good.  For performance, you should also include an explain plan and information about the table sizes and indexes.

Comment: And which relationships are `1:Many` to cause you to need the `DISTINCT`, as well as all constraints, indexes, etc.

Comment: Note: you are not selecting any columns from `FROM signature sig`. DISTINCT raises red flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the junction table out of the main query:

---

```
SELECT af.ID, af.nom_flux, st.chemin_stockage, af.hash_flux 
FROM JOIN stockage st 
INNER JOIN allotissement_flux af 
   ON EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM signature sig
        WHERE st.id_flux = sig.id_flux
        AND af.ID = sig.id_flux
        AND sig.statut_signature = 'A_SIGNER'
        AND sig.nb_appel_service_signature < 4 
        AND sig.date_statut_signature >= sysdate - 100
        )
WHERE st.statut_stockage = 'OUI'
AND st.date_statut_stockage >= sysdate - 100
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should replace `DISTINCT` with `WINDOW` clause.

Also, you can refactor your SQL a bit to improve its performance. Since you are not picking any columns from `signature` table however you are filtering certain records based on this table. lets apply these filters at the time of join itself. It may bring up some improvement with execution time.

Sample SQL -

```
SELECT ID, nom_flux, chemin_stockage, hash_flux FROM (SELECT af.ID, af.nom_flux, st.chemin_stockage, af.hash_flux, rank() over (partition by af.ID, af.nom_flux, st.chemin_stockage, af.hash_flux order by af.ID) as rrank
FROM allotissement_flux af   
INNER JOIN stockage st ON st.id_flux = sig.id_flux AND st.date_statut_stockage >= sysdate - 100 AND st.statut_stockage = 'OUI'
INNER JOIN signature sig ON af.ID = sig.id_flux  AND sig.date_statut_signature >= sysdate - 100 AND sig.statut_signature = 'A_SIGNER' AND sig.nb_appel_service_signature < 4)) WHERE rrank = 1;
```